# Firebird: What index to create for selecting the last record?

Tags: sql, firebird

I select the last record (via a timestamp field) of a subset of the records in a table and want to create a useful index to speed up the query. To my surprise I was not able to define an index Firebird is willing to use. Also I didn't find any examples or hints to my problem on the internet. So, maybe I find some help here.

I have a table like this

```
create table MDE_ST (
  ID            integer not null,
  RESOURCE_ID   integer not null,
  STARTTIME     timestamp not null,
  ...
  primary key (ID),
  foreign key (RESOURCE_ID) references RESOURCES
);
```

and a query like this

```
select *
from MDE_ST
where RESOURCE_ID = ?
order by STARTTIME desc
rows 1
```

My problem is, the query is really slow. Firebird always uses the foreign key index on resources to execute the query. But there are only a few dozen resources but ten thousands of records per resource. So Firebird do kind of natural scan within the records of the resource.

I try the index

```
create index MDE_ST_ASC on MDE_ST (RESOURCE_ID, STARTTIME);
```

and

```
create desc index MDE_ST_DESC on MDE_ST (RESOURCE_ID, STARTTIME);
```

but nothing changes. Firebird always uses the index of the foreign key. And before you ask: The index statistics are up to date.

My question: What index must I create to speed up the query?

Comment: Change your query to not use `SELECT *`, the optimiser will more than likely disregard any indexes you have as it will read everything as that's what it wants.

Comment: @dbajtr: In the real query there is no `select *`. It's only here to simplify the question.

Comment: to know what index you need you'll need to show the query. If you searching on `Resource_ID` but want everything then just having an index on that column would make sense, not sure what the `Von` key is for without looking at the query

Comment: Oh, Im sorry. While translating the code to english I forgot the field name in the index definition. Edited my question.

Comment: Again, without looking at the full query I'm assuming alot. I dont think the `STARTTIME` is necessary. Because your searching on the `Resource_id` and getting more columns it will use the FK to search for the ID then use a `key lookup` to get the other columns from the table. It would make sense if you just wanted those two columns but not if you want more

Comment: @dbajtr: After re-reading your second comment I tried an descending index on `STARTTIME` only. This one is used by the optimizer and it's way faster for those `resource_id` with ten thousands of records.

Comment: Can anyone explain why a specialised descending index on `resource_id, starttime` isn't used by the optimizer?

Comment: Which version of Firebird; not it might be better to ask this on the Firebird-support mailinglist, or maybe even Firebird-devel.

Comment: @Mark: I have tested it with Firebird 2.1.5 (and ODS 11.1) and Firebird 2.5.7 (and ODS 11.2).

Comment: Look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RKgmD-NefM
It tells you haw Firebird selects an index.
You probably have to uptdate statistics (SET STATISTICS INDEX MDE_ST_DESC)

Comment: You could also try adding the plan to the SQL Query:
    SELECT *
    FROM MDE_ST
    WHERE
    RESOURCE_ID = ?
    ORDER BY STARTTIME DESC ROWS 1
    PLAN(MDE_ST INDEX(MDE_ST_DESC))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
create desc index MDE_ST_DESC on MDE_ST (STARTTIME);
```

Comment: Thanks. That index does a better job. Especially on those `resource_id` with ten thousands of records (see my comment above).

Answer (score 1):

[INDEX](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-ddl-idx.html)

> All indexes in Firebird are uni-directional. An index may be
>   constructed from the lowest value to the highest (ascending order) or
>   from the highest value to the lowest (descending order). The keywords
>   ASC[ENDING] and DESC[ENDING] are used to specify the direction of the
>   index. The default index order is ASC[ENDING]. It is quite valid to
>   define both an ascending and a descending index on the same column or
>   key set.
>
> A descending index can be useful on a column that will be subjected to
>   searches on the high values (“newest”, maximum, etc.)

When you use "ORDER BY " **DESCENDING** you should use descending index for this column.

In other words, **the direction of index should be the same as the direction of "order by"**.